# Classic ASP Cross-Site Scripting

Tags: security, asp-classic, xss, cross-site

I am novice in web development and that too now I need to work on classic ASP project. Main agenda is to remove security issues of old code instead of developing new things.

Initially, I've got many SQL Injection issues. I was successful in removing SQL Injection using parametric queries. But, once after that same code was showing Cross-Site Scripting : Persistent issue. Then, I used `Server.HTMLEncode("")`. Even it was successful in removing that issue. But, now it is showing as **Cross-Site Scripting : Poor Validation issue**.

### Cross-Site Scripting : Persistent

```
<TD> <% =rs("hse_desc")%> </TD>
```

### Cross-Site Scripting : Poor Validation

```
<TD> <% =(Server.HTMLEncode(rs("hse_desc")))%> </TD>
```

Could anyone please help me in sorting out this issue.

Comment: My client company will use their in-house software to check for security issues. I don't know any details about that software. And also, let me ask one question,  can I get that kind of software to check myself and review the code again and again.

Comment: Add logic to your asp form code which checks for referring domain, and if the domain is not white listed reject the submission.

Comment: The tool used to check for vulnerability should provide more details the "poor validatino issue", and also information on how to solve it, otherwise it is not very useful.

Answer (score 2):

It's just saying your encoder is weak:

http://www.hpenterprisesecurity.com/vulncat/en/vulncat/java/cross_site_scripting_poor_validation.html

What static code analyzer are you using?

*Please run screaming from Classic ASP. There really is no way to secure it. IMHO

Answer (score 0):

Did you directly use <% =rs("hse_desc")%> in your code.
if this data directly send with cross site, it is a vulnerability and anyone can inject data in this code.

you have to set this data to new variable and secure it with a function like this

```
function clearme(value)
 if value = "" then exit function
 value = replace(value,"'","")
 value = replace(value,"`","")
 value = replace(value,"%","")
 value = replace(value,"<","&lt;")
 clearme= value
end function

if len(rs("hse_desc")) > 1 then
  mydata = clearme(rs("hse_desc"))
else
  mydata = ""
end if
```

now datam is a clear value to use anywhere in code

Comment: How it differs from Server.HTMLEncode(""). If I set this data to new variable and invoke above function, will it remove all types Cross-Site Scripting attacks. (Poor Validation, Persistent and Reflected)

Comment: server.HTMLEncode only a way to correct something like space char with %20 and & chars with &amp;

Comment: After using the function, do I need to use like <TD> <%= Server.HTMLEncode(mydata) %></TD> Or directly, <TD> <%= mydata %> </TD> is enough.

Comment: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   <!--
    window.location.href = "./includes/download.asp?path=<%=path%>&file=<%=file_name%>"
   //-->
  </SCRIPT>

Comment: What should I do in above case. Could you please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a false positive. Your code

```
<TD> <% =(Server.HTMLEncode(rs("hse_desc")))%> </TD>
```

will solve any XSS issues (as long as you only do this for HTML output, not JavaScript).

I think your static analyser may be picking up that this is some weak construct that can't be secured. Try removing the superfluous brackets:

```
<TD> <%=Server.HTMLEncode(rs("hse_desc"))%> </TD>
```

The "Poor Validation" issue is referring to output code that cannot properly HTML encode. Some languages and frameworks do not support proper encoding. So the advisory is saying that in these cases you should validate input, rather than encode on output. For example, if the user is entering a phone number you should ensure that the phone number is only using whitelisted characters (e.g. say `0` to `9` and `-#()`) and make sure that these are the only characters that are output in the case that your input comes from elsewhere.

In your case however, I don't think that this applies.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Basically, I am writing like following.                                         <TD>
<%=HTMLDecode(Server.HTMLEncode(rs("hse_desc")))%>
</TD>                                                                                       Why because, when I use Server.HTMLEncode("") only all the white spaces and all are unable to display properly in HTML page.

Comment: Where, HTMLDecode function defined as, <%
Function HTMLDecode(sText)
    Dim I
    sText = Replace(sText, "&quot;", Chr(34))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&lt;"  , Chr(60))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&gt;"  , Chr(62))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&amp;" , Chr(38))
    sText = Replace(sText, "&nbsp;", Chr(32))
    For I = 1 to 255
        sText = Replace(sText, "&#" & I & ";", Chr(I))
    Next
    HTMLDecode = sText
End Function
%>

Comment: And also yes as u said, now I am including pages that display info from DB only in this project. I mean other than Select operations, there are no insert, delete, update operations.

Comment: @kpgu1718: Sounds like your DB data is already HTML encoded in some places. There is little point in decoding and encoding in the same function call like that.

Comment: Yes, it is encoded. But to bypass from Security issue I am using Server.HTMLEncode("") and to display properly I am using HTMLDecode("") function.

Comment: <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
   <!--
    window.location.href = "./includes/download.asp?path=<%=path%>&file=<%=file_name%>"
   //-->
  </SCRIPT>

Comment: What should I do in above case. Could you please help me.